# Attaching an array to shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have read lines in from a .txt file and now wish to attach the array/strings to memory so I can access it with.. I think what I have is on the right track? I am able to get the lines into an array and access with `words[0]` for example. I am just not sure how to make them accessible through shared memory.. I think I need to do something in my if..else.. in the last block of code I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
int main() {
    const key_t key = 12345678;
    FILE *ptr_fp;
    char words[600][600];
    int i = 0;  
    ptr_fp = fopen("messages.txt","r");    

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(float) * 8, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    printf("Created a shared memory segment of 32 bytes.\n");


    if (ptr_fp != NULL){
        while(fgets(words[i],600,ptr_fp )&& i <600){
            i++;
        }
    }

    /*for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("%s",words[j]);
        if(j == 3){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }*/

    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        char *addr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (addr == (char *)(-1)) {
            perror("shmat error");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            printf("Shared memory attached at address %p\n", addr);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "attaching" an array to shared memory? Normally you'd create a shared memory segment and then map it, using its address space *as* your array. In your example, `words` is in local process memory, not shared memory.

Comment: Apologies. Yes that is what I meant to say. I would like to be able to access the array in another process to be able to view/print out the array contents.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the array to be in shared memory, then the array's first byte needs to be the address returned by shmat.

It looks like you're populating the array and then trying to "tell something" that you want to share your array.

It would be convenient if it worked that way but it doesn't.

I suppose you could copy the bytes from the array to the shared memory segment but that would be wasteful.

EDIT 1

As you become more familiar using shared memory and as your use case becomes more complicated (e.g., Oracle's shared memory segment(s)) you'll want to pay attention to  John Bollinger's comment below.

Comment: is char* words = (char*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0); on the right track?

Comment: @AlexTurner Yes, or even `char (*words)[600] = ...` if you want to mimic the original memory layout.

Comment: @AlexTurner Yes, you'll get there eventually.

Comment: More generally, the array's first byte needs to be at a well-known or computable offset into the shared memory segment (not necessarily 0), and the segment needs to be big enough to accommodate the whole thing, taking the offset into account.  The point is that one could put more in the shared memory segment than just the one array, though it does not appear that the OP needs to do so for his present purposes.